# java how to make a rectangle move by time

Tags: java, graphics, paint

i'm trying to make a program which when user clicks it gets the coordination and move that rectangle to that coordination by time what i'm trying learn is how to make a tick when moving
(I didnt make classes i just need to know the idea of the way to do that)

Answer (score 3):

You would probably want to use a Timer and a TimerTask to move the rectangle every second or so.

Example:

```
public class Reminder {
    Timer timer;

    public Reminder(int seconds) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds * 1000);
    }

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            System.out.format("Time's up!%n");
            timer.cancel(); //Terminate the timer thread
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Reminder(5);
        System.out.format("Task scheduled.%n");
    }
}
```